Is std::atomic or volatile necessary when setting variables from a signal handler
#include <unistd.h>

#include <csignal>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::function<void(int)> g_signalHandler;

void signalWrapper(const int a) { g_signalHandler(a); }

int main() {
    bool abort = false;
    g_signalHandler = [&abort](const int) {
        std::cout << "Abort" << std::endl;
        abort = true;
    };

    struct ::sigaction signalAction = {};
    signalAction.sa_handler = signalWrapper;

    if (
        ::sigaction(SIGHUP,  &signalAction, nullptr) != 0 ||
        ::sigaction(SIGINT,  &signalAction, nullptr) != 0 ||
        ::sigaction(SIGTERM, &signalAction, nullptr) != 0
    )
        throw std::exception();

    // Is it guaranteed that the new value of abort will be seen here without
    // the need of std::atomic<bool> or volatile bool?
    while (!abort)
        ::sleep(1);

    return 0;
}

Assume a single threaded program, C++17, and Linux
To the best of my knowledge using a normal bool is adequate for while (!abort) and std::atomic<bool> / volatile bool is not necessary. I would like to confirm that this is always true and that I don't have to worry about the compiler optimizing out reading the value

volatile static std::sig_atomic_t

@TedLyngmo I am using C++17

@asimes Yes, that works fine in C++17 too.

@TedLyngmo I now understand that volatile will ensure the value is read each time and that std::sig_atomic_t will ensure it can be written in a single instruction. However, why static?

I haven't read the motivation behind that and I can't find any mentioning of that it has to be static in the C++23 standard either. Perhaps cppreference.com got it wrong - or that's just how it was before C++11.


To the best of my knowledge using a normal bool is adequate for while (!abort) and std::atomic / volatile bool is not necessary. I would like to confirm that this is always true and that I don't have to worry about the compiler optimizing out reading the value

No, that is wrong and will cause a data race, which is always undefined behavior.
To demonstrate how such undefined behavior could reasonably manifest: The compiler may see that abort is non-atomic and that ::sleep does not imply any synchronization. Therefore it can conclude that abort will never change if it is initially false, since that would cause a data race with undefined behavior, and either get rid of the loop check completely or keep abort in a register without ever reloading it from memory. In either case, your loop will never terminate.
volatile bool is also wrong. volatile is not sufficient according to the requirements of the standard for signal handlers.
volatile does guarantee that each read and write in the code will actually translate to a load and store, however volatile does not make any guarantee on atomicity of these loads/stores. (However, specific compiler/platform combinations may make such guarantees, so that volatile may be used to implement atomic operations.)
The only non-local variables you are guaranteed to be able to access with defined behavior in a signal handler are (non-thread-local)

objects of type volatile std::atomic_sig_t (and accessed through volatile glvalue); only if shared (without other synchronization) exclusively between the signal handler and the thread on which the signal handler runs, no other threads
lock-free atomic objects; std::atomic_flag is guaranteed lock-free; which ones of the std::atomic specializations are lock-free is platform-dependent and can be checked with the is_lock_free and is_always_lock_free members of std::atomic

Furthermore, library functions are by default not safe to use in a signal handler either. There are only specific exceptions in the C/C++/POSIX standards. Specifically std::function and stream IO as in std::cout <<  are not safe in signal handlers and also cause undefined behavior.
See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal for the requirements that the C++ standard imposes on signal handlers in order for them to have well-defined behavior according to the standard.
And see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_16_04_03 for a list of async-signal-safe functions in POSIX environments.

After reading some it seems that the requirements of std::signal (which I don't use) are much more strict than sigaction. Specifically it seems that sigaction should be blocking another signal from executing while the signal handler is active significantly reducing the number of problems that can occur

@asimes That doesn't help too much. One signal handler interrupting the thread is enough to cause problems. Examples: Writing to the bool (whether volatile or not) may be done by the compiler in two instructions and the signal can interrupt between them, causing an invalid state to be visible. std::cout << may use a lock shared with other IO operations. If the interrupted thread holds the lock, then you deadlock in the signal handler. (Which is why non-lock-free atomics also don't work in signal handlers.)

Calling the std::function is the only thing that seems unlikely to me to cause problems in practice. However, the implementation is allowed to e.g. use some shared global state to implement std::function that might be modified on a call, for whatever reasons.
